# Symfony 1.4 connect to frontend_dev.php/ return a browser 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, symfony-1.4

I'm having big trouble with the server configuration on my local machine for my symfony1.4 application.

When i'm accessing localy my debug environement with this URL :  mywebsite.adrien.sf1/frontend_dev.php/ it ends up with a browser 404 error

Not Found
The requested URL /frontend_dev.php/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at mywebsite.adrien.sf1 Port 80

Bug when i'm accessing with this URL : mywebsite.adrien.sf1/frontend_dev.php it works fine but i can only access this page, other pages give me the same error as above.

The .htaccess is OK because we tried to use a backup and it ends up with same error. Concerning the vhost we tried to use a backup too and same error too.

rewriting module is active and works cause when I access this url mywebsite.adrien.sf1/ (production mode) all the website work just fine.

It seems that when I access this url mywebsite.adrien.sf1/frontend_dev.php/ apache try to access a folder named frontend_dev.php with a path like ..../public_html/mywebsite/web/frontend_dev.php/.

I searched for hours and can't find any answer to my problem ?

Does someones already faced this problem ?

Thx in advance

My Vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite.adrien.sf1

        DocumentRoot /home/adrien/public_html/mywebsite/web
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <Directory /home/adrien/public_html/mywebsite/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order Allow,deny
                Allow from All
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.mywebsite.fr-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.mywebsite.fr-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In your settings.yml, is no_script_name set to false for all environments except for prod?

Comment: Yes it is. We finally decide to create a new container with fresh apache, php, mysql install and the problem disappear. I think this isn't a symfony 1.4 related problem